# Error when assigning a boolean value

Tags: c#

I am getting an error while assigning a value.

My code is:

```
    protected bool ValidateProfile()
    {
       bool blnFirstName = false;
       bool blnLastName = false;
       bool blnEMail = false;

      //(error on line below: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer")
       ValidateProfile() = false;


   if txtFName != ""
      blnFName = true;

   if txtLName != ""
      blnLName = true;

   if txtEMail != ""
      blnEMail = true;

   if (blnFName) && (blnLName) && (blnEMail))
     ValidateProfile = true;

    }
```

How do I assign a boolean value to ValidateProfile ?

Thanks

Comment: @John Saunders - VB programmers are welcome here just like everyone else. It is a legit question.

Comment: As others have said, you want to use `return false` for this, but in case you didn't know and it isn't obvious, `return` will immediately return you from the function...just something to be aware of.

Comment: @Nick: I don't think John was dissing him...just remarking on the programming world the person came from.  You'll note that John actually gave a highly voted correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Beska, I am aware that return will just out of the function. So return = false does not really solve my issue. Thanks for the info

Comment: @Nick, John was actually responding to my comment..which I had removed.. my comment was "whaaaat??" as for a moment I forgot that  languages other than C# exist in this world :P

Comment: I'm wondering why the downvote?  This seems like an honest question from a person new to the language.

Comment: @Nick: what in the world made you think I was dissing him? If I'd meant "VB and FORTRAN programmers are idiots", then, believe me, I would have said so.

Comment: Ewwww.. Hungarian Notation (of the worst kind)

Comment: @Earlz, what notation do you prefer?

Comment: Microsoft officially distanced itself from Hungarian notation around the time of the 2005 PDC conference (if memory serves).  With modern IDE's and type safe languages, the benefits of Hungarian notation are more limited and it tends to make code a bit harder to read.

Comment: @Stan R. @John Saunders - I saw the down vote, and then yours was the only comment, so I associated the two. I didn't realize there was an earlier comment which got deleted, and was associated with the down vote. That's why I assumed you were dissing the person. With the added context of the deleted comment, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: @Nick, no problem. btw, I never downvoted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, in C# you use `return` instead of `MyFunction = x`. In this scenario, you can assign the result of your final check to a boolean and return it:

```
bool retVal =  (blnFName) && (blnLName) && (blnEMail);
return retVal;
```

Alternatively, you could just skip the assignment altogether:

```
return (blnFName) && (blnLName) && (blnEMail);
```

EDIT: I noticed you are using hungarian notation, which implies that txtFName is a TextBox.  Keep in mind that C# doesn't have default properties like VB.  If it is a TextBox, it will never equal "", because it's not of type `System.String`. I'm guessing you actually wanting to evaluate `txtFName.Text`

Comment: Using a separate bool for each field and &&ing them is not good practice.

Comment: @Jeremy: yes, I am evaluating txtFName.Text

Comment: Be sure to set up your project with Option Strict On to catch many common issues.

Comment: @Nate: which part? the separate bool fields or &&ing multiple bool values? granted you could return false evaluating each boolean individually, but it ends up being the same operation.

Comment: @Jeremy: The separate fields. There's nothing wrong with &&ing multiple bools but there isn't any reason for multiple bools in this case.

Comment: Good call. You could probably write the entire method in a single line.

Answer (score 7):

You want

```
return false;
```

In C#, we don't assign values to the function name in order to return a value.

---

If you want to set the return value at a different point in time from when you return from the method, then you should do something like this:

```
bool retVal; // Defaults to false

if (condition)
    retVal = true;

if (otherCondition)
    retVal = false;

if (thirdCondition)
    retVal = true;

return retVal;
```

Comment: John, I need to use the expression (if ValidateProfile then do this) in other places in the app. How can I do that using a retVal ?

Comment: if(ValidateProfile()) { /*then*/ }

Comment: You would write if (ValidateProfile()) { /* Do Stuff */ }

Comment: @user, thats what you do if(ValidateProfile()) { //do this}, remember for comparison you need to use "==" like so if(ValidateProfile()==false) { // do something }

Comment: @Dykam, I know..i am just showing an example in which I think he is getting confused with equality operator and assign operator. In VB you use "=" for both.

Comment: @user: it looks like you really need some help with the very basics of C#. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx.

Comment: @Stan R, ah, I though it may be confusing to compare to false :P.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a value to a function.  You need `return false;`

Answer (score 2):

You want to `return false`

---

Alright, taking the code you posted:

```
protected bool ValidateProfile()
{
      return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEMail);
}
```

Or

```
protected bool ValidateProfile()
{
    bool returnValue = true;

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFName))
    {
         returnValue=false;
    } 
    else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLName))
    {
         returnValue = false;
    } 
    else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEMail))
    {
         returnValue = false;
    }

    return returnValue;

}
```

Though you could just return false as soon as you find an invalid field.

Answer (score 2):

Change that last line to:

```
return false;
```

Although it seems you're always returning false here.  Is there an option to return true?

Comment: yes, I modified my code block up above; the code block checks to see if user has entered values, then set ValidateProfile = true.

Comment: Great.  You need to use "return" plus a value of the type of the method's return value type when returning a value from a method in C#.

Comment: Can you post an exmaple, plz?

Comment: wont the processor jump out of the code block after "return = false;"  ?

Comment: Yes it will jump out of the block, but what it's really doing is "returning a value to caller".  When you just use `return;`, it basically translates to `return void;`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note besides all the returns...

You may want to change this:

if txtFName != ""

To check if the String.IsEmptyOrNull(txtFName.Text)

Or at least initialize your variables to either null or String.Empty.

Just an FYI though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a C# programmer, but can't you just write:

```
return (txtFName != "") && (txtLName != "") && (txtEMail != "");
```

for the body of the function?

Comment: In c# you should use String.IsNullOrEmpty(variable)

Comment: Thanks Nate.  Does C# evaluate a NULL string to false?  How about an empty string?

Comment: In C# a string does not have any implicit conversion to boolean.  If you try it, you'll get an error.  You have to use some kind of function on the string that will return a boolean, such as in your answer, or @Nate's response.